# New line character handling in sqoop import to hdfs

Tags: sqoop

I have a situation where need to migrate data to hdfs from postgres using sqoop, copy that file to s3 and create Hive external table.
Problem am facing that in few of the fields in postgres I have New line character in data. How can I handle that to migrate to HDFS? I understand that it can be done in Hive, but need to how it can be done in HDFS.

Looking for help....

Answer (score 0):

Textual fields with newlines in them can be handled by sqoop by choosing ORC or avro files generation instead of text.

By the way if you d'like to bridge postgres and hdfs to import/export data from postgres I recommend you to take a look at apache spark, in particular the [spark-postgres](https://github.com/EDS-APHP/spark-postgres) library which support newlines in text fieds.